# How can I count the code paths in an empty foreach statement for PHPUnit code coverage?

Tags: php, phpunit

I have started playing with PHPUnit and am quite perplexed with a foreach statement.
I have created a simple function:

```
public function testForEach(array $x): void {
   foreach($x as $k => $v) ; //empty foreach
}
```

I applied PHPUnit and it says that there are 3 paths in the function.
The paths that I know about are:

1. The empty array []
2. An single item array, e.g. [1]

I tried to input an array with 2 elements [1, 2] and an associative array ['x' => 1], but the tool states that I have found 2 out of three paths. I even tried [1, 2, 3, 4, 5] to no avail.

Does anyone know what the 3rd path is?

If I change the empty statement to a simple `echo $x;`, the result is still 3 paths, so it has nothing to do with the empty statement.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Traced it back at the PHPUnit level, the library used is phpunit/php-code-coverage.

PHPUnit makes the following checks for a simple foreach loop:

- The empty array [], exits before entering any commands behaves like an if at the start of loop.
- At least one pass, in my example [1]. This ensures that the loop is executed at least once.
- No iterations and no checking, like null in my example. It seems there is a condition at foreach that $x is iterable, and it needs to fail.

Comment: The condition at foreach that $x is iterable is to test for the error condition. No need to test for that in your own test code, as it is a test in itself already, so you have it automatically asserted.